# Uniform sampling (by volume) within a rectangular pyramid

Tags: python, math, geometry

I learned how to [uniform sampling (by volume) within a cone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41749411/uniform-sampling-by-volume-within-a-cone?rq=3). But I have no idea how to uniform sampling (by volume) within a rectangular pyramid. Especially when I have known the intrinsic params of the camera. Can anyone help?

I don't know how to get the probability of the width and length of the base.

Comment: You can split the pyramid into two tetrahedra.

Answer (score 0):

Same principle

Three randoms `u,v,t` in range 0..1

```
t2 = t^(1/3) 
y = h * t2
x = t2 * (2*u-1) * width/2   
z = t2 * (2*v-1) * length/2
```

for the case when (0,0,0) is in the top of pyramide, pyramide height falls into base center.